# Can the Bousfield class of projective space be computed directly?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, chromatic-homotopy

Recall that the Bousfield class of a spectrum $E$, written $\langle E\rangle$, is the class of spectra $X$ such that $X\wedge E$ is not contractible. For example the Bousfield class of any of the spheres $\mathbb{S}^k$ is the class of all noncontractible spectra.

Now take the complex projective space $\mathbb{CP}^n$, choose a basepoint and consider the suspension spectrum $\Sigma^\infty\mathbb{CP}^n$. I think it follows from the thick subcategory theorem of Hopkins-Smith that the Bousfield class $\langle \Sigma^\infty\mathbb{CP}^n\rangle$ is equal to $\langle \mathbb{S}^k\rangle$ (it's a "type 0" finite spectrum). But that theorem seems rather high-powered for the job it's doing here.

So my $\textbf{question}$ is: can the the Bousfield class $\langle \Sigma^\infty\mathbb{CP}^n\rangle$ be computed directly?

For example for $n=1$, $\Sigma^\infty\mathbb{CP}^1\simeq \mathbb{S}^2$ so things are looking good. For $n=2$, since $\Sigma^\infty\mathbb{CP}^2$ is the cone $C(\eta)$ of the Hopf map $\eta:\mathbb{S}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^2$ one can use the facts that

1. $C(\eta^k)$ can be gotten as the cofiber of (suspensions of) $C(\eta^{<k})$'s and
2. $\eta^4$ is null

to deduce that if $X\wedge \Sigma^\infty\mathbb{CP}^2$ is contractible then so is $X\wedge (\mathbb{S}\vee \mathbb{S}^5)$, so $X$ is contractibe, and hence $\langle \Sigma^\infty\mathbb{CP}^2\rangle=\langle \mathbb{S}\rangle$.

Comment: Hopkins' and Smith's proof of their thick subcategory theorem uses arguments not so different than yours.  Note that you have used the nilpotence of $\eta$ in your little argument for $\mathbb CP^2$; they, of course, have the Nilpotence theorem to play with.

Answer (score 15):

Here is an easy argument which sometimes works.  I have updated and extended it to incorporate comments from Dylan Wilson and Maxime Ramzi.

For any finite spectrum $X$, we have (co)unit maps $S\xrightarrow{\eta}DX\wedge X\xrightarrow{\epsilon}S$.  Given any $f\colon X\to X$ we can form the composite
$$ \Lambda(f) = (S \xrightarrow{\eta} DX\wedge X 
    \xrightarrow{1\wedge f}
    DX\wedge X \xrightarrow{\epsilon} S) \in 
    [S,S] = \mathbb{Z}.
$$
This can be computed by the usual Lefschetz formula
$$ \Lambda(f) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} (-1)^n 
    \text{trace}(f_*\colon H_n(X;\mathbb{Q}) \to H_n(X;\mathbb{Q}))
$$
If there exists $f$ with $\Lambda(f)\neq 0\pmod{p}$, then $S$ is $p$-locally a retract of $DX\wedge X$, so the Bousfield classes $\langle X\rangle$ and $\langle S\rangle$ are equal.

Now consider the case where $X=\Sigma^\infty\mathbb{C}P^n$ for some $n>0$.  In the unstable category, cellular approximation gives
$$ [\mathbb{C}P^n,\mathbb{C}P^n] = 
   [\mathbb{C}P^n,\mathbb{C}P^\infty] =
   [\mathbb{C}P^n,K(\mathbb{Z},2)] =
   H^2(\mathbb{C}P^n) = \mathbb{Z}.
$$
If we write $f_q$ for the map corresponding to $q\in\mathbb{Z}$, then the effect on the cohomology ring
$$ H^*(\mathbb{C}P^n)=\mathbb{Z}[x]/x^{n+1} = 
    \mathbb{Z}\{1,x,\dotsc,x^n\}
$$
is given by $f_q^*(x^k)=q^kx^k$.  Put $\lambda(n,q)=\Lambda(\Sigma^\infty f_q)$.  When calculating this, it is the trace of $f_q^*$ on *reduced* cohomology that is relevant, giving
$$ \lambda(n,q) = q + q^2 + \dotsb + q^n = 
    q(q^n-1)/(q-1).
$$

- If $p\nmid n$ then $\lambda(n,1)\neq 0\pmod{p}$
- Now suppose that $p\mid n$ but $p-1\nmid n$ (so $p>2$).  Let $q$ be a primitive root mod $p$, so in particular $q-1$ is invertible mod $p$, so there is no problem with interpreting the formula $\lambda(n,q)=q(q^n-1)/(q-1)$ modulo $p$.  We then find that $\lambda(n,q)\neq 0\pmod{p}$
- Now suppose that $p(p-1)\mid n$.  By considering the cases $q=0\pmod{p}$, $q=1\pmod{p}$ and $q\neq 0,1\pmod{p}$ separately, we find that $\lambda(n,q)=0\pmod{p}$ for all $q$.

In conclusion:

- If $p(p-1)\not\mid n$ then the above method proves that $\langle\mathbb{C}P^n\rangle=\langle S\rangle$
- If $p(p-1)\mid n$ then we still know from nilpotence theory that $\langle\mathbb{C}P^n\rangle=\langle S\rangle$, but the above method does not suffice to prove it.

Comment: doesn't the same argument (by considering the Lefschetz trace) prove the general case? (the map $\mathbb{C}P^n \to \mathbb{C}P^n$ with Euler class $p$ times the generator should have trace equal to 1 mod $p$, giving the sphere as a retract of $\mathbb{C}P^n \wedge D\mathbb{C}P^n$.)

Comment: @DylanWilson see my correction to the answer - the relevant trace here is the trace on the reduced homology, which is zero mod $p$.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use a map with Euler class $q$ then ? I think in this case the reduced trace is $\sum_{1\leq i\leq n} q^i = q \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$. This nonzero (hence invertible) mod $p$ if and only if both $q$ and $q^n-1$ are. So we just pick a $q$ not divisible by $p$, and such that $q^n$ is not $1$ mod $p$. If all nonzero $q$'s satisfy $q^n = 1$ mod $p$, then $(p-1)$ divides $n$. So if $(p-1) \nmid n$ or $p\nmid n$, this can be made to work.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I think you are right, I went through that analysis previously but miscalculated slightly.  So that just leaves the case where $n$ is divisible by $p(p-1)$.

Comment: With this strategy, in the triangle $F \to S \to DX \wedge X$ you are showing that the map $F \to S$ is null. In general if $X$ is type $0$, this map is just tensor nilpotent, not necessarily null, right? Could it happen that the map $F \to S$ is not null when $X$ is a complex projective space?

Comment: @JamesCameron I think that $F\to S$ is not null in the case $X=\mathbb{C}P^2$ with $p=2$.